# How do I add a hidden element to a flex parent element without changing the other elements' size?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, hidden

I am trying to create 6 buttons of the same size as children of a flexbox element. Before showing the buttons there should be a plus exactly between the spot where the two middle buttons will apppear. For that I included the plus within the same div as the buttons and toggle the visibility of the plus and the buttons using JavaScript. 
The problem I have is that the hidden plus takes up place within the parent element and changes the size of the other children elements. How can I include a hidden element that does not change the other child elements?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="button-wrapper" id="allButtons">
        <button id="button0"><span></span><p></p></button>
        <button id="button1"><span></span><p></p></button>
        <button id="button2"><span></span><p></p></button>
            <span id="fixation-cross"><strong>+</strong></span>
        <button id="button3"><span></span><p></p></button>
        <button id="button4"><span></span><p></p></button>
        <button id="button5"><span></span><p></p></button>
    </div>

#fixation-cross {
    visibility: hidden;
    font-size: 44px;
    color: black;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

button span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}

button {
    position: relative;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 10px; 
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.button-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    height: 50vh;
    align-items: flex-end;
}  

button:disabled {
    background: lightgrey;
}

button:disabled span {
    opacity: 1;
}

#allButtons {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Thank you a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try making the hidden 'plus' have a `position: absolute` and the flexbox element should have `position: relative`. You can then center the 'plus' using`top bottom right and left` properties

Answer (score 0):

You can force the `#fixation-cross` element width to be 0, it will then not count into the flex spacing.

Doing so, the `+` sign is then shifted to the right, so we need to somehow move it of half of its size to the left. Unfortunately the `transform: translateX(-50%)` trick won't work as 50% of 0 is definitely 0.

To achieve the trick I forced the width of the inner `strong` element with a fixed width and set its display property to `block` to ensure it will be this size exactly. I also center align the text in order to be sure the `+` sign is in the middle.
All this allows me to transform the parent and translate it to the left of half the width of its content, as we now know exactly how much it will be.

The result in the snippet below:

```css
#fixation-cross strong{
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
}

#fixation-cross {
    width: 0;
    transform: translate(-15px);
    font-size: 44px;
    color: black;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

button span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}

button {
    position: relative;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 10px; 
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.button-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    height: 50vh;
    align-items: flex-end;
}  

.button-wrapper button{
  background-color: red;
}

button:disabled {
    background: lightgrey;
}

button:disabled span {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-wrapper" id="allButtons">
        <button id="button0"><span></span><p></p></button>
        <button id="button1"><span></span><p></p></button>
        <button id="button2"><span></span><p></p></button>
        <span id="fixation-cross"><strong>+</strong></span>
        <button id="button3"><span></span><p></p></button>
        <button id="button4"><span></span><p></p></button>
        <button id="button5"><span></span><p></p></button>
</div>
```